# AMAZON AWS S3 recursively change/add metadata for an entire bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, http-headers, metadata

I have an S3 bucket in which files will be downloaded from. For each file I would like to add the following metadata:

```
'Content-Disposition: attachment'
```

Is there a global/easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using http://s3browser.com/ which made it very easy to make bulk changes!